# SQL - How to calculate product discount and get products where discount is greater than 25?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate discount in SQL query and want to get products having discount greater than 25. I am trying with following query. Please correct me what i am doing wrong.
Thank you

```
SELECT *, (product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price*100 as p_discount
FROM `products`
WHERE product_price IS NOT NULL
  AND p_discont > 25
ORDER BY p_discount DESC
```

I am getting following error.

> `#1054 - Unknown column 'p_discont' in 'where clause'`

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT list. I.e. the column alias hasn't been defined yet, and cannot be use in WHERE. Either use the same calculation one more time, or have a cte or derived table. (Or, MySQL special, use HAVING clause.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use inline condition in where clause

```
SELECT *, (((product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price)*100) as p_discount
FROM `products`
WHERE product_price IS NOT NULL
  AND (((product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price)*100) > 25
ORDER BY p_discount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you just miss spelled p_discont, maybe you should try with p_discount

```
SELECT *, (product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price*100 as p_discount
FROM `products`
WHERE product_price IS NOT NULL
  AND p_discount > 25
ORDER BY p_discount DESC
```

Comment: Not working even i correct the p_discount. Thanks for you response.